# Facebook bot appearing as a non-messenger user on certain phones

Tags: facebook, location, bots, messenger

We've created a facebook bot and it's still in testing.  On some testers phones (ios) the bot user is appearing as a non-messenger user and we believe this is preventing the user from sharing their location.  The same user can use the messenger web app and share their location there.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Cheers

Ross

Comment: Not quite sure why or how but re-installing the messenger app on the tester's phone fixed this issue for us.  Hopefully this will help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why or how but re-installing the messenger app on the tester's phone fixed this issue for us. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future – Ross Ellerington